How to define a function that returns a variable storing plots instead of plotting them to the output
I define a simple function that returns variables storing plots:
MyPlot[a_, b_] := Module[{plot1, plot2},
  plot1 = Plot[Sin[x - a], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All];
  plot2 = Plot[Cos[x - b], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All];
  {plot1, plot2}
]

When I run it
plots = MyPlot[1, 2]

the plots are stored in plots but are also displayed in the output.
How to prevent the latter and have the plots only stored in plots without being explicitly plotted in the output?
I tried to add DisplayFunction->Identity but it doesn't work.

Semicolon should do the job plots = MyPlot[1, 2];

Use Hold
MyPlot[a_, b_] := Module[{plot1, plot2},
  plot1 = Plot[Sin[x - a], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All];
  plot2 = Plot[Cos[x - b], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All];
  Hold[{plot1, plot2}]
]

plots = MyPlot[1, 2]


Hold[{plot1$2326056, plot2$2326056}]

plots // ReleaseHold


